# Windows Store App flipview margin

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, border, margin, viewflipper

With this simple XAML code :

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="230" Height="300" Background="Red" Margin="0">
        <FlipView Background="Blue" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Result :

[image: flipView margin example]

How to remove the flipview transparent "margin" which show the red Grid background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of the default style of the FlipView control.

To remove it you need to copy this default style (posted below) and remove the margin in the border:

```
<Style x:Key="FlipViewStyle1" TargetType="FlipView">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <Border.Resources>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M4.12,0 L9.67,5.47 L4.12,10.94 L0,10.88 L5.56,5.47 L0,0.06 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.55,0 L9.67,0.06 L4.12,5.47 L9.67,10.88 L5.55,10.94 L0,5.48 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0.06,0 L5.47,5.56 L10.88,0 L10.94,4.12 L5.48,9.67 L0,4.12 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.63,0 L11.11,5.55 L11.05,9.67 L5.64,4.12 L0.23,9.67 L0.17,5.55 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Border.Resources>
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="NextButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Simply change the margin property on the border :

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
```

by :

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

`FlipView` tends to keep a small margin. If you just force it a `Margin=-3` it will show your desired output. Alternatively, you can add another element just to make sure no "light" passes from behind without hacks.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="230" Height="300" Background="Red">
        <Grid Background="Blue">
            <FlipView/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: the margin minus three is a great hack, but it does affect the swiping a bit

Comment: @JPHellemons How does it affect the swiping? I use the flipview occupying the full screen, so I never see anything  else.

Comment: I was unable to get to the last page somehow.